# How to grab values on different pages and assert them

Tags: cypress

I am following POM and have classes for Cart and Order confirmation pages.
On the cart page e.g. I need to grab the values like price, qty, product name and validate the values once the order placed.
How can I store these values and use it later in the test to verify on order confirmation page?

**CartPage.js**

`static getProductName() { return cy.get('#product-name') }`

**checkout.cy.js**

`import CartPage from "../pagesObjects/pages/CartPage"`

// so when my script is on cart page then how can I grab the value and then validate on order confirmation page

```
  CartPage.getProductName().invoke('text').then((cartProductName) => {
            // how to store the value and then use later in the test?          
        })
```

Answer (score 3):

Cypress provides alias commands to save data for later.

```js
import CartPage from "../pagesObjects/pages/CartPage"

it('tests my checkout', () => {
  CartPage.getProductName().invoke('text').as('cartProductName')

  // later in the test
  cy.get('@cartProductName').then(cartProductName => {
    ....
  })
})
```

But across tests the alias values are cleared down.

In this case, use the POM class itself to save the value.

```js
class Cart {

  static productName

  static getProductName() { 
    const selection = cy.get('#product-name')
    selection.invoke('text')
      .then((cartProductName) => {
        Cart.productName = cartProductName  // save to static member
      })
    return selection
  }
}

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit('my-page-under-test')   // saves even after reloading the web page
})

it('fills the cart', () => {
  Cart.getProductName()
})

it('tests the checkout', () => {
  cy.wrap(Cart.productName).should('eq', 'cabbage')
})
```

Comment: Fixed a mistake in the referencing of static member.

Comment: Thanks Sidika able to resolve by using alias in the test.

Answer (score 0):

If you are re-using the values in the same test, you can use Cypress environment variables to store data.

```js
it('tests something', () => {
  const cartPage = new CartPage();
  cartPage.getProductName().invoke('text').then((cartProductName) => {
    Cypress.env('cartProductName', cartProductName)
  });
  cy.get('foo') // getting another element
    .should('have.text', Cypress.env('cartProductName')) // asserting it has the same text as `cartProductName`
});
```

Alternatively, you can store the value in a variable outside of the initial scope.

```js
it('tests something', () => {
  let cartProductName;
  const cartPage = new CartPage();
  cartPage.getProductName().invoke('text').then((text) => {
    cartProductName = text
  }).then(() => {
    expect(cartProductName).to.eql('foo'); // assert using Chai
    cy.get('foo').should('have.text', cartProductName); // or using Cypress
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks agoff! However, I am not getting the value from invoke
My html looks something like below:

<div class="line-item-name text-wrap mb-0"> == $0
 <a data-test-id="nameLink">Hair Brush</a> // I want to fetch this value

CartPage.js
static getCartValues() {
   cy.get('[data-test-id="nameLink"]')
})

checkout.cy.js
    CartPage.getCartValues()
            .invoke('text').then((cartProductName) => {
               Cypress.env('cartProductName', cartProductName)
             });

cy.log("ProductName is", Cypress.env('cartProductName')) //prints empty

Comment: You'll need to return `cy.get(...)` -> `getCartValues() { return cy.get(...) }`